# How do I test a try and catch block in Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I've tried a lot of different things from the Internet, but haven't found anyone exception handling try and catch blocks with just Mockito.
Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
public void add() throws IOException {
        try {
            userDAO.insert(user);
            externalContext.redirect("users.xhtml");
        } catch (final DuplicateEmailException e) {
            final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                    "Die E-Mail Adresse wird bereits verwendet.");
            facesContext.addMessage(emailInput.getClientId(), msg);
        } catch (final UserAlreadyInsertedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

and then here's how I'm trying to test it right now:

```
@Test
    public void addTest() throws IOException, UserAlreadyInsertedException, DuplicateEmailException {
        User user = mock(User.class);
        doNothing().when(userDAO).insert(user);
        doNothing().when(externalContext).redirect(anyString());
        doNothing().when(facesContext).addMessage(anyString(),any());
        try{
            initMirror();
            userAddBean.add();
            verify(userDAO, times(1)).insert(user);
            verify(externalContext, times(1)).redirect(anyString());
        }
        catch (DuplicateEmailException e){
            verify(facesContext,times(1)).addMessage(anyString(),any());
        }
        catch (UserAlreadyInsertedException e){
            doThrow(IllegalStateException.class);
        }

    }
```

I'm pretty sure that especially the last part where I try to catch and throw an exception is wrong but I really can't find a good tutorial on this.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Try changing `doNothing().when(userDAO).insert(user);` to `doThrow(new DuplicateEmailException()).when(userDAO).insert(user);`

Comment: You seem to be wanting to test several different flows of execution (which is a good thing); each different one should be in a separate test method. Generally, you'll have at least one "happy" test method (no exceptions), then you'll have methods where you'll say something like `when(stuff).thenThrow(anException)`, and make sure that you get a message in your `facesContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write separate test cases for `DuplicateEmailException` and `UserAlreadyInsertedException`.
 It will be good if you have one test case for positive scenario.

The first test for `DuplicateEmailException`

```
@Test
public void addTestForDuplicateEmailException() throws IOException, UserAlreadyInsertedException, DuplicateEmailException {
    User user = mock(User.class);
    doNothing().when(externalContext).redirect(anyString());
    doNothing().when(facesContext).addMessage(anyString(),any());
        
    Mockito.when(userDAO.insert(Mockito.any(User.class))).thenThrow(new DuplicateEmailException());
       
    initMirror();
    userAddBean.add();
    verify(userDAO, times(1)).insert(user);
    verify(externalContext, times(1)).redirect(anyString());   
}
```

Second test for `UserAlreadyInsertedException`

```
@Test
public void addTestForUserAlreadyInsertedException() throws IOException, UserAlreadyInsertedException, DuplicateEmailException {
    User user = mock(User.class);
    doNothing().when(externalContext).redirect(anyString());
    doNothing().when(facesContext).addMessage(anyString(),any());
        
    Mockito.when(userDAO.insert(Mockito.any(User.class))).thenThrow(new UserAlreadyInsertedException());
       
    initMirror();
    userAddBean.add();
    verify(userDAO, times(1)).insert(user);
    verify(externalContext, times(0)).redirect(anyString());   
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, but I have void methods so instead of this:
```
Mockito.when(userDAO.insert(Mockito.any(User.class))).thenThrow(new UserAlreadyInsertedException());
       
```
I tried this:
```
doThrow(IllegalStateException.class).when(userDAO).insert(any(User.class));
```
However I'm still getting a stubbing mismatch error

Comment: Try `doThrow(new DuplicateEmailException()).when(userDAO).insert(any(User.class))`